# Plot multiple boxplot in one graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I saved my data in as a `.csv` file with 12 columns. Columns two through 11 (labeled `F1, F2, ..., F11`) are `features`. `Column one` contains the `label` of these features either `good` or `bad`.

I would like to plot a `boxplot` of *all these 11 features* against the `label`, but separate by `good` or `bad`. My code so far is:

```
qplot(Label, F1, data=testData, geom = "boxplot", fill=Label, 
          binwidth=0.5, main="Test") + xlab("Label") + ylab("Features")
```

However, this only shows `F1` against the `label`.

My question is: How to show `F2, F3, ..., F11` against the `label` in one graph with some `dodge position`? I have normalized the features so they are in the same scale within [0 1] range.

The test data can be found [**here**](http://ge.tt/81I9owW/v/0?c). I have drawn something by hand to explain the problem (see below).

[image: hand-drawn boxplot example]

Comment: (+1) Your post had everything, but not quite formatted. I guess that was the down-vote for. Please learn to use the SO formatting options! It'll help you a lot. Also, instead of posting link to CSV, you should use `dput(testData)` and paste the output here so that people can directly copy/paste on their system.

Comment: Thanks very much, Arun. I will try to format my future post. I was trying to paste the data but found it contained so many numbers. But I should create a smaller toy problem.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You should get your data in a specific format by melting your data (see below for how melted data looks like) before you plot. Otherwise, what you have done seems to be okay.

```
require(reshape2)
df <- read.csv("TestData.csv", header=T)
# melting by "Label". `melt is from the reshape2 package. 
# do ?melt to see what other things it can do (you will surely need it)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var = "Label")
> df.m # pasting some rows of the melted data.frame

#     Label variable      value
# 1    Good       F1 0.64778924
# 2    Good       F1 0.54608791
# 3    Good       F1 0.46134200
# 4    Good       F1 0.79421221
# 5    Good       F1 0.56919951
# 6    Good       F1 0.73568570
# 7    Good       F1 0.65094207
# 8    Good       F1 0.45749702
# 9    Good       F1 0.80861929
# 10   Good       F1 0.67310067
# 11   Good       F1 0.68781739
# 12   Good       F1 0.47009455
# 13   Good       F1 0.95859182
# 14   Good       F1 1.00000000
# 15   Good       F1 0.46908343
# 16    Bad       F1 0.57875528
# 17    Bad       F1 0.28938046
# 18    Bad       F1 0.68511766

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label))
```

[image: boxplot_ggplot2]

**Edit:** I realise that you might need to facet. Here's an implementation of that as well:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
             geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label))
p + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
```

[image: ggplot2_faceted]

**Edit 2:** How to add `x-labels`, `y-labels`, `title`, change `legend heading`, add a `jitter`?

```
p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Label))
p <- p + geom_jitter()
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
p <- p + xlab("x-axis") + ylab("y-axis") + ggtitle("Title")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend_Title"))
p
```

[image: ggplot2_geom_plot]

**Edit 3:** How to align `geom_point()` points to the center of box-plot? It could be done using `position_dodge`. This should work.

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Label))
# if you want color for points replace group with colour=Label
p <- p + geom_point(aes(y=value, group=Label), position = position_dodge(width=0.75))
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free")
p <- p + xlab("x-axis") + ylab("y-axis") + ggtitle("Title")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend_Title"))
p
```

[image: ggplot2_position_dodge_geom_point]

Comment: Another question: how to change the x lable and y lable using this method? For example, NOT using 'value' and 'variable'. Thanks so much.

Comment: scale_x_discrete(name="xxx") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="yyy")

Comment: I am wondering how to add 'adding raw data points' overlaid on the boxplot. I suppose to use geom_point() or geom_jitter(); however, as I tried, the points overlaid together and can't be separated into two groups, ie, good or bad here.

Comment: Thanks very very much for your help. Just last bit, I want to overlay the raw data points on the boxplot. I tried both geom_point() or geom_jitter(). For example, when I use geom_point(), the data points from both 'good' and 'bad' data sets overlaid together and shown in the middle of the orange and blue boxes shown above. However, I want the raw points overlaid separately along the middle line (whisker) of each box. Sorry to bother you again, but please help me to look at this issue. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Check **Edit 3**. I think this should do it. You should be able to take care of other edits/transformations by reading the ggplot2 manual [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/)

Comment: 1. Just noticed that this lne

p <- p + geom_point(aes(y=value, group=Label), position = position_dodge(width=0.75))

gave a warning: "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead"

Found a solution online

p <- p + geom_point(aes(ymax=max(value), group=Label), position = position_dodge(width=0.75))

However, not clear that why "position_dodge" needs ymax instead of y. Just a note for other people who want to get clear of warning.

Comment: 2. I may should check the documents of position_dodge, however, may I just ask a quick question:
Why position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) works? How to choose this value of width=0.75?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: There is a way to scale each boxplot? I managed to get boxplot but outliers are too "out" and they hide the boxplot.

Comment: Someone knows how to change the order in which the boxplots are shown ? i have a similar problem but the only thing that is still bothering me is the order the of the boxplots. In the above example, "good" before "bad" for example. I have more than 2 labels and would like to specify the order in which the boxplots are displayed

Answer (score 27):

Using base graphics, we can use `at =` to control box position , combined with `boxwex =` for the  width of the boxes. The 1st `boxplot` statement creates a blank plot.  Then add the 2 traces in the following two statements.

Note that in the following, we use `df[,-1]` to exclude the 1st (id) column from the values to plot. With different data frames, it may be necessary to change this to subset for whichever columns contain the data you want to plot.

```
boxplot(df[,-1], boxfill = NA, border = NA) #invisible boxes - only axes and plot area
boxplot(df[df$id=="Good", -1], xaxt = "n", add = TRUE, boxfill="red", 
  boxwex=0.25, at = 1:ncol(df[,-1]) - 0.15) #shift these left by -0.15
boxplot(df[df$id=="Bad", -1], xaxt = "n", add = TRUE, boxfill="blue", 
  boxwex=0.25, at = 1:ncol(df[,-1]) + 0.15) #shift to the right by +0.15
```

[image]

Some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep("Good",200), rep("Bad", 200)),
  F1 = c(rnorm(200,10,2), rnorm(200,8,1)),
  F2 = c(rnorm(200,7,1),  rnorm(200,6,1)),
  F3 = c(rnorm(200,6,2),  rnorm(200,9,3)),
  F4 = c(rnorm(200,12,3), rnorm(200,8,2)))
```

Answer (score 20):

Since you don't mention a plot package , I propose here using `Lattice` version( I think there is more ggplot2 answers than lattice ones, at least since I am here in SO).

```
 ## reshaping the data( similar to the other answer)
 library(reshape2)
 dat.m <- melt(TestData,id.vars='Label')
 library(lattice)
 bwplot(value~Label |variable,    ## see the powerful conditional formula 
        data=dat.m,
        between=list(y=1),
        main="Bad or Good")
```

[image]

Comment: Another question: how to change the x lable and y lable using this method?

Comment: @SamoJerom you add e.g : `ylab="value"`, `xlab="treatment"` to the bwplot statement

Comment: @agstudy I am wondering how to add 'adding raw data points' overlaid on the boxplot. I suppose to use geom_point() or geom_jitter(); however, as I tried, the points overlaid together and can't be separated into two groups, ie, good or bad here.

Answer (score 13):

ggplot version of the lattice plot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("TestData.csv", header=T)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var = "Label")

ggplot(data = df.m, aes(x=Label, y=value)) + 
         geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable,ncol = 4)
```

**Plot:**
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the title of multiple boxplot or include a specific ylab for each variable?
I would like to include the name and units of variables.
Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a bit of an older question, but it is one I had as well, and while the accepted answers work, there is a way to do something similar *without* using additional packages like ggplot or lattice. It isn't quite as nice in that the boxplots overlap rather than showing side by side but:

```
boxplot(data1[,1:4])
boxplot(data2[,1:4],add=TRUE,border="red")
```

[image: picture of what this does.]

This puts in two sets of boxplots, with the second having an outline (no fill) in red, and also puts the outliers in red. The nice thing is, it works for two different dataframes rather than trying to reshape them. Quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 6):

In base R a formula interface with interactions (`:`) can be used to achieve this.

```
df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/TestData.csv")
df <- data.frame(stack(df[,-1]), Label=df$Label) # reshape to long format

boxplot(values ~ Label:ind, data=df, col=c("red", "limegreen"), las=2)
```

[image: example]

Comment: There is a way to facet the boxplot?