# R Merging Boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to use R to show a merged boxplot, I am sure this is easy, I just am missing something:

```
boxplot(WHO$Male, WHO$Female, ylim=c(0,100))

boxplot(WHO$Female ~ WHO$Year, ylim=c(0,100))
boxplot(WHO$Male ~ WHO$Year, ylim=c(0,100))
```

All three work, but when I try:

```
boxplot(WHO$Male ~ WHO$Year, WHO$Female ~ WHO$Year, ylim=c(0,100))
```

It returns:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
   cannot coerce class ""formula"" to a data.frame
```

Note, Year, only contains three numbers, 1990, 2000, 2010

```
> head(WHO)
  Year WHO.region      Country Male Female
1 1990     Africa      Algeria   66     68
2 1990     Africa       Angola   39     43
3 1990     Africa        Benin   45     50
4 1990     Africa     Botswana   63     66
5 1990     Africa Burkina Faso   45     49
6 1990     Africa      Burundi   47     50
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merged boxplot".  You want them both on one plot, side by side?  And please post a few lines of the data.

Comment: So, if you do Male, Female, you get two boxplots, one showing males data, and one showing females data.  If you do Male ~ Year, you get males data broken by year.  I want Male and Females data side by side, broken by year

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.  Are you trying to get years on the x-axis? I'm not sure `boxplot` is the right plot for that.

Comment: Yes, both Years, and Gender on x-axis.  I created a paint image of what I think it should look like:  http://s1.postimg.org/h5k527udb/123.png, color being Male, Female

Comment: Sigh. First argument to `boxplot.formula` should be a formula and second argument should be a data.frame. Makes no sense to give two formulas to `boxplot`. (Read the help page.)

Comment: Ok, but what should the formula be?  Since its both, WHO$Male ~ Year AND WHO$Female ~ Year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reshape2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html) package does something similar. Actually there was quite similar question - [Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph), maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: I had to change how my data was formatted, so I could follow the guide, but it works very well.