# Different scales of multipanel plots using lattice package in R

Tags: r, lattice

I followed the script of agstudy [in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph/23928317#23928317) and produced panel of box-plots like this [Figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk71m2ioto1try7/Rplot.png)

But the I have a different kind of problem; the ranges of the variables are different. Therefore, plots except for 'moisture' are not properly scaled. How can I force lattice to scale the plots as per their own range? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. It makes it difficult for people to help you if we have to go around chasing down the code and the data.

Answer (score 7):

With lattice, you can make each panel have it's own scales with the "relation" property. The "free" option lets all of the panels be independent. See `?xyplot` for other options.

```
 bwplot(value~Label |variable,    ## see the powerful conditional formula 
        data=dat.m,
        between=list(y=1),
        main="Bad or Good", scales=list(relation="free"))
```