# Plot group in lattice, using different data sources

Tags: r, lattice

Using the `lattice` package in R, I would like to plot one row of 7 diagrams, all using the same Y-axis. The diagrams should be (vertical) line diagrams. The problem is that my data are each in 7 separate dataframes (containing X and Y data), with different slightly different limits on the Y-axis data.

Besides all tutorials, I don't get it right. What must my Code look like? Is there even a clean solution for this in `lattice`?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928834/different-scales-of-multipanel-plots-using-lattice-package-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine all your data frames into one and then do something like

```
xyplot(Y~X|odf,data=combinedDF,layout=c(7,1))
```

where `odf` is an indicator column of the original data frame. This by default should use a common y scale.

Apart from combining the data, you could create 7 separate plots, then print them.

```
p1 <- xyplot(Y~X,data=DF1,ylim=c(Y1,Y2))
p2 <- xyplot(Y~X,data=DF2,ylim=c(Y1,Y2))
etc.
```

To print:

```
print(p1,split=c(1,1,7,1),more=TRUE)
print(p2,split=c(2,1,7,1),more=TRUE)
...
print(p7,split=c(7,1,7,1),more=FALSE)
```

see `?print.trellis`.

Of course, arranging single plots like this doesn't really use the features of `lattice`. You could just as easily do this with base graphics using `layout` or `par(mfrow=c(1,7))` for example, and a common `ylim`.