# How to add a p value line to a boxplot

Tags: r

This should be simple but I can't find the answer. All I want to do is add a line to a plot drawn at a specific y value starting at a specific x value and ending at a specific x value. The abline function doesn't seem to have a start and end parameter. How do I do this in r for normal (non ggplot) plots

Comment: `abline(h=pvalue)` for a horizontal line at the p-value

Comment: Do you mean drawing a `segment`?

Comment: Yes that worked. I guess in the end its about finding the right word to google. I used this---par(lend=2);segments(1,37,2,37,lwd=6)

Comment: Or `lines()`, where you simply repeat your y value twice.

Comment: This seems to be asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263046/how-to-draw-the-boxplot-with-significant-level/29263992#29263992

Comment: Nope. thats for ggplot. This is for base plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general case, to plot a line from point `(x_1, y_1)` to point `(x_2, y_2)`, simply use `lines(c(x_1, x_2), c(y_1, y_2))`