# add boxplot significance indicator lines and asterisks in R plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot

What is the R plot_ly command to add horizontal significance bars (and stars) to a plotly graph? The answers to ["How to draw the boxplot with significant level?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263046/how-to-draw-the-boxplot-with-significant-level) and ["Put stars on ggplot barplots and boxplots - to indicate the level of significance (p-value)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084566/put-stars-on-ggplot-barplots-and-boxplots-to-indicate-the-level-of-significanc) provide good code for ggplot.

First, determine significance:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(lm(data = iris, Sepal.Width ~ Species), pairwise ~ Species)
     $contrasts
     contrast               estimate         SE  df t.ratio p.value
     setosa - versicolor       0.658 0.06793755 147   9.685  <.0001
     setosa - virginica        0.454 0.06793755 147   6.683  <.0001
     versicolor - virginica   -0.204 0.06793755 147  -3.003  0.0088
```

Here is example R code for the plot. How do I add lines and stars?

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_boxplot(p, data = iris, x = ~Species, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                 color = ~Species, boxpoints = "all", jitter = 0.3, pointpos = 0)
# p <- add_paths(p, data = iris, ???)
# p <- add_line(p, data = iris, ???)
p
```

Comment: If you want to do via annotations toggling will not work anymore (the significance indicator will stay while the trace is gone). Any of the possibilities will be quite hacky and a one-off-solution, adding a trace which functions as a indicator, adding annotations, etc.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, thanks for the comment. It sounds like you're recommending against using R Plotly to add these significance indicators. I'll add them in Inkscape or Illustrator and save as SVG.

Comment: If you disable trace toggling and you are fine with a hacky solution, I could add one.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but it seems to me that if you're successful, what you will have is a very cluttered graph. I might suggest using instead the cld() function with lsmeans to incorporate grouping letters in the tabular output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horrible hacky solution which gives the desired output

- Adding the brackets as a separate line trace
- Adding the significance markers as labels on top of hidden bar plots
- Hiding the helper categorical values via `layout`

The problem with using annotations is that there is no way of putting the asterisk in the right place, three boxplots means three categorical x-values. The new x-values are added via the bar plot.

[image]

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_bars(p, 
              x = c('setosa', 'setosa0', 'versicolor', 'versicolor0', 'virginica'),
              y = c(3.5, 4.6, 2.5, 4.1, 3),
              opacity=1,
              showlegend = F,
              marker=list(line = list(color='rgba(0,0,0,0'),
                          color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0'),
              text = c('', '**', '', '*', ''),
              textposition = 'outside',
              legendgroup = "1"
)
p <- add_lines(p, 
               x = c('setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'versicolor'),
               y = c(4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.5),
               showlegend = F,
               line = list(color = 'black'),
               legendgroup = "1",
               hoverinfo = 'none'
)

p <- add_lines(p, 
               x = c('versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica'),
               y = c(4.0, 4.1, 4.1, 4.0),
               showlegend = F,
               line = list(color = 'black'),
               legendgroup = "1",
               hoverinfo = 'none'
)


p <- add_boxplot(p, data = iris, x = ~Species, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                 color = ~Species, boxpoints = "all", jitter = 0.3, pointpos = 0,
                 legendgroup="1")


p <- layout(p,
            xaxis = list(tickmode = 'array',
                         tickvals = c('setosa', 'sf', 'versicolor', 'vet', 'virginica'),
                         ticktext = c('setosa', '', 'versicolor', '', 'virginica')),
            yaxis = list(range = c(0, 5))
            )
p
```

The graph below shows all the hidden traces used to get the graph right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clever and detailed explanation! I tried making a function but gave up because the method is too idiosyncratic. I wonder how hard it would be to add this feature to Plotly? 
(Your answer has a formatting issue with the code.)

Comment: @KayleSawyer: I hope the Plotly is working on it. Thanks for spotting the formatting error, amazing what single missing new line can do ;)

Comment: It is shameful that there is not a more straightforward way to do this