# Wrong results in calculating boxplot significance levels in R

Tags: r, boxplot, t-test

I am working on creating a basic boxplot with significance level bars (as showed here: [How to draw the boxplot with significant level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263046/how-to-draw-the-boxplot-with-significant-level))

The data I use is as follows:

| title1 | title2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 8.88 |
| 2 | A | 5.84 |
| 3 | A | 13.28 |
| 4 | A | 16.89 |
| 1 | B | 21.39 |
| 2 | B | 20.77 |
| 3 | B | 28.03 |
| 4 | B | 19.78 |
| 1 | C | 28.89 |
| 2 | C | 35.41 |
| 3 | C | 37.47 |
| 4 | C | 50.11 |
| 1 | D | 50.84 |
| 2 | D | 53.21 |
| 3 | D | 46.47 |
| 4 | D | 45.03 |

With the following code, creating the boxplot works fine. For the significance bars, I want to use paired t tests like title2=A vs. title2=B, with the two rows with title1=1 being a pair and so on.

In R, I entered the following command, but it yields different results for p. For instance, the p-value for A vs. D should be 0.003, but R yields 2.8e-05. What is the correct syntax for a paired t test?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(bxp, aes(y=value,x=title2)) +
xlab("Behandlung") + 
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Kontrolle","Stretch","Hyperoxie","Stretch & Hyperoxie")) + 
ylab("Zelluläre Seneszenz (%)") + theme_classic() + 
geom_boxplot(coef = Inf) + 
geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("A","B"),c("A","C"),c("A","D")), test=t.test, map_signif_level=FALSE, step_increase=0.08)
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Dave2e It's difficult to tell from the data whether a paired or unpaired test is called for, but having run both on the data myself, OP's expected result is produced by the paired version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggsignif` is computing the unpaired t-test, and I think you want the paired test. Luckily `geom_signif` has a `test.args` argument, which will allow you to pass `paired = TRUE` to the geom:

```
ggplot(bxp, aes(y=value,x=title2)) +
  xlab("Behandlung") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Kontrolle","Stretch","Hyperoxie","Stretch & Hyperoxie")) + 
  ylab("Zelluläre Seneszenz (%)") + theme_classic() + 
  geom_boxplot(coef = Inf) + 
  geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("A","B"),c("A","C"),c("A","D")), test=t.test, test.args = list(paired = T), map_signif_level=FALSE, step_increase=0.08)
```

#### Data:

```
bxp <- structure(list(title1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                1, 2, 3, 4), title2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                                        "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"), value = c(8.88, 5.84, 
                                                                                                           13.28, 16.89, 21.39, 20.77, 28.03, 19.78, 28.89, 35.41, 37.47, 
                                                                                                           50.11, 50.84, 53.21, 46.47, 45.03)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Jdobres, you are amazing. Just didn't know how to use test.args properly. Huge thanks ❤️