# box plots in R compaing multiple data vectors over multiple groups

Tags: r, boxplot

i have stream temp data and I'd like a a figure with box plots comparing daily mean and daily max (2 columns in data set) by site and year (each a column in data set). daily mean and daily max would be next to each other in the plot for each year (chronologically) and then years grouped by site. 
i can plot daily mean or daily max individually with the code: 
boxplot(data~year+site)
but can i add another data variable to be plotted?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is not a code-writing or data-guessing service. Please provide a [reproducible examle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph)