# Mean/standard deviation plot of survey items with missing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, stata

I'm an R beginner attempting to do what I figured (erroneously) would be a beginner-type task: produce a simple plot of means/standard deviations for multiple survey questions (vectors), grouped by a second variable (say, group).

So I am reading variables (say, q1-q10) into R from Stata and have even managed to `melt` the data following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph).

What I would like is essentially the graph presented in the solution:

[image]

However, my data contain missing values (`NA`), and the *NUMBER* of missing values varies by question.  So when I try to use `ggplot` to plot the 'melted' data, I get an error saying the vector lengths do not match.

Comment: Without an example of your data and some code showing what you tried to do, your question is almost impossible to answer. For more info on generating a reproducible example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Like I said, I am interested in how one can produce a specific type of plot -- namely, plot of means/standard deviations for multiple vectors grouped by a second variable, all of which contain missing values -- rather than code for a specific example.

Comment: Please re-read @JanvanderLaan comment. You should provide a (simulated) dataset and offending code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose that your variables q1-q10 are separated, then you should merge them into a data frame df:

```
df <- data.frame(q1, q2, ...,q10)
```

And then you can clean it such that you only have complete cases, i.e. only observations without NA:

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Afterwards, you should not have problems with ggplot.