# Boxplot with many variables and categories

Tags: r, boxplot, summary

Is is possible to create something like this in R?

I have 7 different variables that i want to include for product A and the same 7 for the rest of the products, B, C...

However I also want to include the summaries vales (min, mean and max).

[image: boxplot]

How can I create this?

I already have all the different variables as a "Value".
I was trying with something like
    protein~product 
but i want for all variables inside the Product AAA. If possible, the same for all products ( i don't know it that will be possible due to the amount of the variables).

this is a part of the data..

```
product  protein  fat  moisture ash  fiber  starch  sugar 
  AAA     49      1.0    NA      NA   10     7.4    6.1 
  BBB     35      1.6    NA      NA   10.6   8.5    10.0 
  AVF     40      1.2    NA      NA    6     7.8    6.3
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided your data by using `dput(MyData)` and then pasting the result into your question.

Comment: @G5W

I tried that but the data base is too big. I cannot see the entire answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can start your adventure with this example.
EDIT: I added some info, how to get from your data format to a long data format, required for the plot.
Also find more info at similar questions:
[Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph)

```
# simulate the data
set.seed(314)

id <- rep(1:100, each = 3)
prod <- paste("product",rep(letters[1:3], each=300))
ing <- rep(c('protein','fat','starch'), 300)
mg <- rnorm(900, 5, 2)

df <- data.frame(prod, ing, mg, id)

#reconstruct your data format
yourdata <- df %>% group_by(id, prod) %>% spread(ing, mg)


library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# get your format in long format
pd <- yourdata %>% gather(ing, mg, -id, -prod)

# use the long format for the plot

ggplot(pd, aes(x = ing, y = mg, fill = ing)) + geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~prod)
```

[image]

Comment: @Wietze134 

This seems really nice! Is exactly want I want to do! 

However, one of my problems is that your "mg" was perfect if the x,mean and sd were equal for all the parameters, right? In my case i need to have the summary of each "ing" per "prod" (analysis per product)...

Comment: Your data shows just 3 rows. If there is one row per product there is not much to summarize, is there?

Comment: @Wietze134 
In total I have 140000 rows.. so I really need to summarize.. This case was just an example, otherwise it will be impossible.. My fault, I forgot to say that.

Comment: Ok no problem. Because I generated my data, it's all the same, but just an illustration. If you use `pd <- yourdata %>% gather(ing, mg, -product)` on your data then it should act the same. There is a way to customize the barplot to plot min, mean, max instead of the normal thing. Info can be found here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html

Comment: @Wieztze134 
I'm not being able to apply your code to my data.. can you help me, please? 
id<- should it be a column with the row number?
prod <- should it be a column with the products?
ing <- should it be the names for my analysis?("protein", "starch"..) cause i only have that information as a head of each column..
mg <- should I change the first number to the same amount of rows that i have in my df?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ana, I tried explaining how you can alter your data with `dplyr` and `tidyr` using the function `gather`. If you can give us the ouput of for example `dput(head(YourDataFrame))` I can help you. In the `gather` statement `ing` and `mg` are the names for the new columns.

Comment: I found out that I needed to melt my data.
Thank you a lot anyways!

Comment: `melt` and `gather` are similar functions. Good you found a solution.