# How do I generate multiple boxplots for multiple independent variables across a data set?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, boxplot, yaxis

I have a device that generates an excel spreadsheet for a number of parameters (e.g. height, biomass, NDVI, density etc.). These independent variables are included in the header names, and all have an assigned numeric value. I would like to generate multiple box plots (one for each variable) that uses the "treatment" column to generate multiple x values.

For example: To create a boxplot with y axis height, and x axis treatment, y axis biomass + x axis treatment and so on.

I know how to do this normally with `ggplot2` and manually input this information, but I'd like advice on how to generate it so that `y = column name`, `x= treatment`.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated :) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can visit this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14604439/6123824

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO.  This is not really a concise coding question.  Please see this link on how to pose questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you want them all in one figure, but with a separate panel for each column, then melt those columns (see `?tidyr::gather`) and use `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`. In other words, reshape the data long so that you instead have one column for "variable" and one column for "values", then set `aes(y = values)` and use `facet_wrap(~ variable)`.

Below is an example with the `iris` data set, using the column `Species` as treatment, and the rest as parameters.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)

iris %>%
  gather(var, val, -Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = val)) +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    x = "Treatment",
    y = "Parameter") +
  theme_bw()
```