# How to make time series of "two boxplots with same date (x-value) but different y values"

Tags: boxplot

I have collected count data highlighting the same thing, but in two different ways. It has been collected on the same dates through a year. I would like to display my collected data in the same plot.

So basically like this [Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph). 
[image]
But maybe where the two box plots are subsummed by a larger box that only has one "entry" to the x-axis at the correct date.

I am able to make the two plots apear on top of each other, but this is not what i desire :)

Two boxplots on top of each other:

[image]

```
ggplot() + geom_boxplot(data=datedata, aes(x=Date, y=Timelinedata1, group=Date) + 
geom_boxplot(data=datedata, aes(x=Date, y=Timelinedata1, group=Date))
```

Hope you can help.

Kind regards
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

How about this? you need the argument `position` to tell `ggplot` how to plot data on the same X value. In this case I used `position = "dodge"` to put them one next to the other.

Since you did not add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I had to make an example dataset.

Load libraries

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

Generate example dataset

```
data1 <- rnorm(100)
data2 <- rnorm(100)
data3 <- rnorm(100)

data.df <- data.frame("1"=data1, "2"=data2, "3"=data3)
plot.df <- melt(data.df)
plot.df$dodge <- c("A","B")
plot.df$dodge <- factor(plot.df$dodge , levels = c("A","B"))
```

Make plot

```
ggplot(plot.df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, fill = dodge),
               position = "dodge")
```

[image]