# ggplot2 grouped boxplot doesn't separate groups for different timepoints

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a simple data set with two groups and a value for each group at 4 different time points. I want to display this data set as grouped boxplots over time but ggplot2 doesn't separate the time points.

This is my data:

```
 matrix
    Replicate Line Day Treatment  X A WT     Marker Proportion
            1    C  10       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos       8.62
            2    C  10       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
            1    C  18       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos      30.50                                                    
            3    C  18       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
            2    C  18       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
            1    C  50       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos      26.10
            2    C  50       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos      31.90
            1    C  80       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos      12.70
            2    C  80       low NA      HuCHuD_Pos      26.20
            1    C  10    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
            2    C  10    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos      17.20
            1    C  18    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos       3.96
            2    C  18    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
            1    C  50    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos      25.60
            2    C  50    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos      17.50
            1    C  80    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos      19.00
           NA    C  80    normal NA      HuCHuD_Pos         NA
```

And this is my code:

```
matrix = as.data.frame(subset(data.long, Line == line_single & Marker == marker_single & Day != "30"))

pdf(paste(line_name_single, marker_name_single, ".pdf"), width=10, height=10)
plot <- 
ggplot(data=matrix,aes(x=Day, y=Proportion, group=Treatment, fill=Treatment)) +
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1))   
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

What do I do wrong?

What I want

[image]

What I get

[image]

Thanks very much for your help!

Cheers, 
Paula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph)

Answer (score 5):

## Edit:

This is how a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for your question could look like:

```
matrix <- structure(list(Day = c(10L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 50L, 80L, 80L, 10L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 50L, 80L, 80L),
                         Treatment = c("low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal", "normal"), 
                         Proportion = c(8.62, NA, 30.5, NA, NA, 26.1, 31.9, 12.7, 26.2, NA, 17.2, 3.96, NA, 25.6, 17.5, 19, NA)),
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Suggested answer using `factor` to 'discretisize' the variable `Day`:

```
ggplot(data=matrix,aes(x=factor(Day), y=Proportion,  fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1)) +
  labs(x ="Day")
```

[image]

Explanation: If we pass a continuous variable to the 'x' axis for a box-plot, `ggplot2` does not convert the axis to a discrete variable. Therefore, in lack of a 'grouping' variable we only get one box. But if we convert the variable to something **discrete**, like a factor, a string or a date, we get the desired behavior.

Also, when you use `dput` or one of the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) it's way easier to find and test an answer than having to try and work with the data description as in the question (or at least I couldn't figure out how to load that example data)

P.S. I think it's a bit confusing to name a variable of class `data.frame` 'matrix' since `matrix` is its own data type in R... ;)

Comment: Brilliant, that does what I wanted and I will keep your other advices in mind as well.

Comment: ;) Excellent. Glad I could help!