# Create multiple bar graphs in one bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
my_DataSet <- {
```

| # | Variable A | Variable B | Variable C | Control Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

```
}
```

Following [Plot multiple boxplot in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604439/plot-multiple-boxplot-in-one-graph), I did a transformation (`new_DataSet <- melt(my_DataSet, id.var = "Control_Group")`) so that the resulting data looks like this:
I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
new_DataSet <- {
```

| # | Control Group | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Variable A | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Variable B | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Variable C | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | Variable A | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | Variable B | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | Variable C | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | Variable A | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | Variable B | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | Variable C | 1 |

```
}
```

### I want to produce a bar graph which shows the percentage of 1s in the control and intervention group along all 3 variables.

I imagine something like the following bar graph:

[image]

What I have done is the following:

```
p <- ggplot(data = my_DataSet)
p + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Variable_A, y = ..prop.., fill = Control_Group), position = "dodge")
```

This results in:

[image]

Which has two issues

- It only displays `Variable A`, not `A`, `B` and `C`
- I only want the percentage for the 1s, not for the zeroes. If I filter my data beforehand, the proportion becomes wrong, however.

Comment: Try with reshaped dataset `new_Dataset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the proportions for each column and each control group and plot the bar graph.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_DataSet %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Control_group) %>%
  group_by(name, Control_group = recode(Control_group, 
                 '1' = 'control', '0' = 'intervention')) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(name, value, fill = Control_group) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: Thanks. It took me some time to get it to work: I had some more stuff in the dataset (Age, Sex etc.) which was logically also moved in the pivot. I had to change the sex from a character into a number (wasn't nice but did the trick). I could remove all other values with `subset(data.frame, logical conditions)` [just left the comment here in case it helps some beginners like me in the future]